# Cheap reliable GPS Unit for geotagging

Tags: geotagging, gps

Can someone please recommend a cheap, reliable GPS unit for geotagging photos? can you please send a link to the product.

It needs to:
- Preferably quickly acquire GPS signal.
- When turned on, record GPS info into GPX file so I can later use the file to geotag my photos with help of software
- Preferably small and light weight
- Decent battery life, so I can be out all day without recharging.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your smartphone, download a GPS tracker and do the sync on your computer.

Comment: I have since try various different things mentioned on this question. The one I liked the most is the cell phone GPS app, then sync the GPS app file with photos with freeware tool. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The Panasonic DMC-ZS-40 is a great travel camera with built-in GPS. Give accurate lat and lon plus name of country,state,county,city, and nearby landmark. Example from by home:
33 48 39 north
117 55 56 west
USA
California
Orange County
Anaheim
Disneyland

You can choose to display all or omit any. 
Great travel camera zoom won't quit
charges with cell phone charger
no discontinued but available on the web.
I just replace mine for about $100. 
Uses US and Russia GPS system